# How can I add a custom path to my Git GUI SmartGit?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, smartgit

Recent changes to git pre-commit hooks have caused my favorite Git GUI SmartGit to stop working. I can't commit because it can't find the `bundle` command.

I know the path to the `bundle` command by writing `where bundle`, but how can I tell this to SmartGit? I can only specify the Git path in the preferences.

Comment: Make sure the PATH your are starting SmartGit with contains the `bundle` command. This path will also be used by forked Git executables.

Comment: Where is that PATH that SmartGit uses defined? I tried to add the path to the `bundle` command to my default path, but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: SmartGit will use the PATH which the environment from which you are starting SmartGit provides. On Linux and OSX, SmartGit provides additional options to adjust the PATH: https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/VM+options#VMoptions-ExtendedPATH

Comment: This worked! @mstrap can you Answer this question with this answer (instead of just a comment) and upvote my question? This makes it easier for other people to find this question and answer and solve this problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartGit and all processes invoked by SmartGit (especially Git itself) will use the `PATH` which is provided by the environment from which you are starting SmartGit. On Linux and OSX, you can also extend SmartGit's `PATH` by adding `path=/additional/path` to `smartgit.vmoptions` (see [SmartGit documentation](https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/VM+options#VMoptions-ExtendedPATH)).